# Drop shadow on a div container?

Tags: css, html, dropshadow

I have a searchbox with auto-suggest that pops a div up underneath it with multiple search string suggestions (like google).  Is it possible to have drop shadow on the auto-suggest box with CSS or will I need a script of some sort?  I tried a background image but the number of suggests can vary from 1 to 10 or 15.

I'd prefer something that works in IE6+ and FF2+ if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 74):

This works for me on all my browsers:

```
.shadow {
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 30px 5px #999;
}
```

then just give any div the shadow class, no jQuery required.

Comment: http://www.css3.info/preview/box-shadow/ - I found this site to have great examples of different shadow effects

Comment: you don't need box-shadow by itself for IE9?

Comment: In the latest versions of the major browsers, `box-shadow` should work properly. No vendor-prefixes required anymore.

Comment: adding to simon verbeke's comment, box shadow wasn't even working for me in ff until I switch from -moz-box-shadow to box-shadow.  +1!

Answer (score 12):

CSS3 has a `box-shadow` property. Vendor prefixes are required at the moment for maximum browser compatibility.

```
div.box-shadow {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #fff;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px 1px #fff;
}
```

There is a generator available at [css3please](http://css3please.com/).

Comment: Just note that for the absolute positioning to work right, the auto-suggest box has to be positioned either absolutely or relatively.

Comment: What if I can't have a fixed height to the auto-suggest box? The number of suggests ranges from 1-15.

Answer (score 3):

```
.shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
    box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The most widely compatible way of doing this is likely going to be creating a second div under your auto-suggest box the same size as the box itself, nudged a few pixels down and to the right. You can use JS to create and position it, which shouldn't be terribly difficult if you're using a fairly modern framework.

Comment: Yup, and you can make a nice main box any shape you like with the right background image, and make an all-black one of the same shape for the drop-shadow and adjust the opacity to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 2):

you might want to try this. Seems to be pretty easy and works on IE6 and Moz atleast.

```
<div id ="show" style="background-color:Silver;width:100px;height:100px;visibility:visible;border-bottom:outset 1px black;border-right:outset 1px black;" ></div>
```

The general syntax is :
border-[postion]:[border-style] [border-width] [border-color] | inherit

The list of available [border-style]s are :

- dashed
- dotted
- double
- groove
- hidden
- inset
- none
- outset
- ridge
- solid
- inherit

Comment: Just adds a border and doesn't drop a shadow.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using the PNG drop shadows.  IE6 doesn't support it, however it will degrade nicely.

http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/dropshadows.html